# display one article from multiple posts per month

Tags: mysql, limit

Please help my knowledge is limited and I have been struggling with this for almost a week  now.

I have a table which allows the user to post to it. I want to display each month that has a post in it e.g.

DEC
OCT
SEPT
AUG
FEB

However, if there has been multiple post in a single month, I only want that month to be displayed once, how do I do this?

So far I have created this:

```
$months = mysql_query("SELECT article_id, content, DATE_FORMAT(date, '%M')
                       AS date
                       FROM article
                       ORDER BY article_id
                       DESC
                       LIMIT 12");


while($row = mysql_fetch_array($months)){
    echo "<a href=\"fullarticle.php?id=" . $row['date'] . "\">" . $row['date'] . "</a><br/>";
}
```

Each month that has a post is displayed the number of times posts have been made, obviously this is not what im after :(

Comment: What `article_id` and `content` do you want to return for a month during which there were multiple articles?

Comment: I had added article_id and content as my idea is the user can click on the month and it will display all the posts from that month. I was thinking I need to select them both to show them when the required month has been selected

Answer (score 0):

Use the `DISTINCT` keyword:

```
SELECT DISTINCT MONTH(date) FROM article ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(MONTHNAME(date)) as post_month
FROM article
```

DISTINCT removes duplicates from the applied columns.